# Use sed/awk to truncate long email headers

Tags: bash, email, awk, sed

I have a long to field in an email header that spans several lines, like this:

```
To: John Smith <johnsmith@example.com>, Alex Smith <alexsmith@example.com>,
    Superman Smith <supermansmith@example.com>, Devin Smith <devinsmith@example.com>,
    Al Smith <alsmith@example.com>, Jane Smith <janesmith@example.com>,
    Thomas Smith <thomassmith@example.com>
```

I want to truncate it to something shorter, like this:

```
To: John Smith <johnsmith@example.com>, Alex Smith <alexsmith@examp...
```

Basically, I want the output to be one line, fitting as much as possible within the width of the terminal window (I'm guessing using the $COLUMNS variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`formail`](http://man.cx/formail) utility is handy here:

```
formail -c < ~/tmp/email.eml | 
sed -r 's/\t/ /g; s/^(.{'$(( $(tput cols) - 5))'}).*/\1 .../'
```

`formail` can be found in the `procmail` package

Using [`tput`](http://man.cx/tput) to query the terminal size

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. I only have one question: formail adds a line to the beginning of the email which says, "From sender@example.com  Tue Sep 30 14:04:24 2014." I can remove this with sed, but I'm just curious why it's there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what context your doing this, but given a file that has an email message in it,

```
 awk -v maxLineSz=${COLUMNS:-80} \
   '/^To:/{if (length() > maxLineSz-4) { $0=substr($0,1,maxLineSz-4) "..." }}1' emailFile
```

**output**

```
To: John Smith <johnsmith@example.com>, Alex Smith <alexsmith@example.com>, Supe...
```

The only lines affected are lines beginning with 'To:'

the `1` at the end, ensures all lines of input are printed.